# .htaccess "pretty urls" breaks images src

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess code to turn blog.php into /blog/ with this code:

```
# --- CUTENEWS[ST]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog(\d+)*$ ./blog.php
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)*$ ./blog.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blogengine/show_news.php?cn_rewrite_url=$1 [L]

# --- CUTENEWS[ED]
```

This works fine, except when I load the web page with /blog/, the images break. If I load the web page with /blog.php or /blog, the images load fine.

I have been searching through all the .htaccess issues people have had on Stackoverflow, and this is as far as I have come to getting things working. The cutenews php is there because I am using cutenews for blog integration in my site.

I appreciate any suggestions. I am pretty new to .htaccess

Comment: It is literally the exact same path. If I change blog.php or /blog to /blog/ the path for images remains the same, but the image fails to load.

Answer (score 1):

You are not accounting for trailing slash. This *RewriteRule ^blog(\d+)*$*  will not match */blog/* .Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+[^/])*$ /blog.php/$1
```

**EDIT:**
As we discussed in chat you needed something else, here it is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /blog.php?route=$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will catch URLS like: /blog, /blog/, /blog/anythig_goes_here/2343/ . Adding 301 Permanent Redirect header, and L meaning don't process other rules.

in your blog.php you can reach 'route' paremeter via:

```
echo $_GET['route'];
```

**EDIT:**

After discussing further, the issue was solved by removing "/" from the begining of the redirect url, so now that rewrite rule line looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ blogposts.php?route=$1 [L]
```

For images, absolute urls need to be used, starting with "/" pointing to your web root.

Comment: Logically what you are saying makes sense. When I put that in, it says "404 page not found"

Comment: give me a sec. Coudl you put exactly the URL you are trying to catch?

Comment: Sure its thinkingofbuying.com/blog/. Btw if I add RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+[^/])*$ ./blog.php then it loads with 404 but images still broken.

Comment: after blog/ you are not tryign to allow digits? like /blog/2343243 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104949/discussion-between-user3259138-and-muhammed-m).

Answer (score 1):

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/blog.php`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/blog/` the base suddenly becomes `/blog/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```